# Error querying data from GridDB and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, griddb

I am trying to query data from GridDB and another database (e.g., PostgreSQL) using a single query, but I am encountering an error. I have verified that both databases (GridDB and PostgreSQL) are running properly and the necessary tables and columns exist. I have also checked the syntax of my query and confirmed that it is correct.

```
SELECT g.column1, p.column2
```

FROM griddb_table g
JOIN postgres_table p ON g.id = p.id
WHERE g.column1 = '100';

The error message I receive is specific to the database I am querying from, such as "relation not found" or "column not found".
ERROR: relation "griddb_table" does not exist